# How to use ConnectToServer method in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ConnectToServer` but getting a connection info error:

[image]

Comment: Well... looks like the `ConnectToServer` method doesn't like the `UIConnectionInfo` instance you pass. The `UIConnectionInfo` class has no [real public documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.regsvrenum.uiconnectioninfo?view=sqlserver-2016) - it's "infrastructure code" you're not supposed to be using directly.  A wild guess: setting `ServerType` to an arbitrary GUID _looks_ wrong.